# NextJs 13 authentication flow with Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to implement firebase auth in next 13 app, i've got it working, but there is only 1 problem, when I sign-out, it doesn't redirect me to signin/signup pages, even though I'm listening the auth state using `onAuthStateChange` which should redirect it when user becomes null, using the `router` but it isn't, in order to make it work, i'd have to close and open the browser window... below is the implementation:

Project Info:

```
"next": "13.4.5",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
```

Project folder structure:

```
src/
    app/
        page.tsx
        layout.tsx
        (auth)/
              signin/page.tsx
              signup/page.tsx
        (main)/
              home/page.tsx
              plans/page.tsx
              profile/page.tsx
              layout.tsx
    components/
    hooks/useSubscription.ts
    context/useAuth.tsx
    hoc/
        ProtectedRoute.tsx
        SubscriptionRoute.tsx
```

the main root layout: `src/app/layout.tsx`:

```js
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { AuthContextProvider } from "../context/useAuth";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "MyApp",
  description: "",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AuthContextProvider>{children}</AuthContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`src/app/page.tsx`

```js
import Home from "./(main)/home/page";

export default () => {
  return <Home />;
};
```

`src/app/(main)/home/page.tsx`

```js
import React from "react";
import ProtectedRoute from "@/hoc/ProtectedRoute";
import SubscriptionRoute from "@/hoc/SubscriptionRoute";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <ProtectedRoute> {/* for authentication purpose */}
        <SubscriptionRoute /> {/* for subscription purpose */}
    </ProtectedRoute>
  );
}
```

`src/hoc/ProtectedRoute.tsx`:

```js
export default function ProtectedRoute({children}) {
  const {user} = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user?.uid) {
        router.push("/signin");
    } else {
      router.push("/home");
    }
  }, [router, user]);
  return <>{user && children}</>;
}
```

`src/hoc/SubscriptionRoute.tsx`

```js
import useSubscription from "@/hooks/useSubscription";

export default function SubscriptionRoute() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { subscription } = useSubscription();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (subscription) {
      router.push("/profile");
    } else {
      router.push("/plans");
    }
  }, [subscription]);

  return <></>;
}
```

`src/context/useAuth.tsx`:

```js
const AuthContext = createContext({});
export const AuthContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth!, (userListener) => {
      if (userListener) {
        setUser(userListener);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });
    return () => unsub();
  }, []);

  const signOut = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await auth?.signOut();
      setUser(null);
    } catch (error) {} finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, signOut}}>{!loading && children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

On `signOut` press, the `onAuthStateChanged` in `useAuth.tsx` should listen and `ProtectedRoute` should throw user back to `signin` page which isn't the case, what happens is when I press `signOut`, I stay on `plans` page but as the `user` becomes null, I get `not subscribed` but it doens't redirect to `signin`, it stays on `plans` page.

Next 13 navigation is kinda new so I was trying to implement a protected robust authentication flow using firebase auth. Therefore, I got stuck and need some assistance regarding the same. If anyone needs any additional info, feel free to ask!